# Backbone.js causes update instead of create

Tags: backbone.js

Anyone know why is that?
I have a collection called Categories. After doing:

```
Categories.create({name: "MyCategory"});
```

or:

```
category = new Category();
category.set({"name" : "MyCategory"});
category.save();
```

I get an "update" request instead of a "create" request. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I was returning the "id" field as one of the defaults since I am autogenerating them myself. Backbone identifies this and assumes the object has already been created.